# Retrofit UnknownHostException in working internet connection :

Tags: java, android, rest, web-services, exception

When I am hitting the web service from with its IP address its working fine but its failing with its host name:

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to
 resolve host "myhostname": No address associated with hostname
```

Please note that I have gone through all the related post, but still don't find an exact answer.

Although, I am obeying all the suggestions related to the problem but still no clue.
I have working internet connection, I increased DNS Timeout limit, Permissions in the manifest everything is set up already.

And if there is no solution, then please suggest is it the right way to call API through IP address?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please share your code and the address that you try to access.

Comment: could u ping to the domain using command line?

Comment: show us code bro

Comment: @NirajSanghani Yes, it says Request Timeout

Comment: I debug into Retorfit (HttpLoggingInterceptor.java) class, it shows the cause "android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)"

Comment: gives us the full base url you are using. Most probably url you are hitting doesn't exist.